# running lambda function from container image which runs bash script after invokes. script working perfctly but still it throw Runtime.ExitError in end

Tags: bash, docker, function, lambda, containers

I am running a lamba function from container image. basically this image runs a bash script while someone invokes it. So the script is working perfctly but still it throw Runtime.ExitError error at the end. How can I fix this?

```
START RequestId: 13b31468-aa8d-45cc-9c9a-b4fcaaca9b79 Version: $LATEST
main.sh
2022-04-05 16:29:09 arghyadockercli01
2022-03-31 17:38:17 aws-cloudtrail-logs-201043775914-116d21af
2022-04-05 18:45:45 dkabdjkdjse
2022-04-04 14:31:41 dsfdhfjdhdhhjkjfhjdhfj
2022-04-04 05:13:06 ghfjgfhjg
2022-04-01 14:10:49 s3-trail-log-1
2022-03-31 15:46:30 s3trail-bucket
file copied 01
main.sh
2022-04-05 16:29:09 arghyadockercli01
2022-03-31 17:38:17 aws-cloudtrail-logs-201043775914-116d21af
2022-04-05 18:45:45 dkabdjkdjse
2022-04-04 14:31:41 dsfdhfjdhdhhjkjfhjdhfj
2022-04-04 05:13:06 ghfjgfhjg
2022-04-01 14:10:49 s3-trail-log-1
2022-03-31 15:46:30 s3trail-bucket
file copied 01
END RequestId: 13b31468-aa8d-45cc-9c9a-b4fcaaca9b79
REPORT RequestId: 13b31468-aa8d-45cc-9c9a-b4fcaaca9b79  Duration: 11095.96 ms   Billed Duration: 11096 ms   Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 49 MB  
RequestId: 13b31468-aa8d-45cc-9c9a-b4fcaaca9b79 Error: Runtime exited without providing a reason
Runtime.ExitError
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.